# Infinite Inclusion and Exclusion in Probability

Tags: probability-theory, inclusion-exclusion

> Is there some way of generalizing the principle of inclusion and exclusion for infinite unions in the context of probability? In particular, I would like to say that $$P\left(\bigcup_nA_n\right) = \sum_nP(A_n) - \sum_{n \neq m}P(A_n \cap A_m) + \ldots$$

Does the above hold when all the infinite sums converge (and the sum of the infinite sums converges)? Also, is there a generalization to avoid the problem of the sums diverging?

Answer (score 17):

It might be useful to recall that the [principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) (PIE), at least in its finite version, is nothing but **the integrated version of an algebraic identity** involving indicator functions.

Namely, consider $n\geqslant1$ events $(A_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$  and let $A=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^nA_i$, then $A^c=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^nA_i^c$ hence
$$
1-\mathbf 1_A=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\mathbf 1_{A_i}).
$$
Using the shorthand $A_I=\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ for every $I\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and expanding the product in the RHS, one gets
$$
1-\mathbf 1_A=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\sum_{|I|=k}\mathbf 1_{A_I},
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\mathbf 1_A=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{|I|=k}\mathbf 1_{A_I}.
$$
Integrating this pointwise identity between functions, using the linearity of the integral and the identity $P[B]=E[\mathbf 1_B]$ for every $B$, one gets the (finite) PIE as we know it.

---

Which steps of this program, if any, could fail in the infinite setting? To examine this question, let us consider some infinite sequence $(A_n)$ of events and imagine we want to write a PIE for $A=\bigcup\limits_nA_n$. In particular, we intend to use the sum of the series $\sum\limits_nP[A_n]$, hence *let us assume that this series converges*. Then the series $\sum\limits_n\mathbf 1_{A_n}$ converges almost surely and $0<1+x\leqslant e^x$ for every $x\geqslant0$ hence
$$
Y=\sum_I\mathbf 1_{A_I}=\prod_n(1+\mathbf 1_{A_n})\leqslant\exp\left(\sum_n\mathbf 1_{A_n}\right),
$$
converges (absolutely) almost surely. The series
$$
X=\sum_I(-1)^{|I|}\mathbf 1_{A_I}
$$
converges absolutely almost surely hence $X=1-\mathbf 1_{A}$, and the corresponding absolute series is $Y$ hence, *if $Y$ is integrable*, then 
$$
E[X]=\sum_I(-1)^{|I|}P[A_I].
$$

---

The considerations above can be summarized as follows.

> Consider some sequence of events $\mathcal A=(A_n)_{n\in N}$ indexed by some set $N$, finite or countably infinite. Consider the events $A=\bigcup\limits_{n\in N}A_n$ and, for every $I\subseteq N$, $A_I=\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}A_i$.
>  If the series $\sum\limits_IP[A_I]$ converges, then the PIE holds for the sequence $\mathcal A$ in the sense that
>   $$
> P[A]=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\sum\limits_{|I|=k}P[A_I].
> $$

Comment: Is there a reference, in a book or an article, that you know of for this countably infinite version of inclusion-exclusion by any chance?

Comment: "Exact conditions for countable inclusion-exclusion identity and extensions" http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~friedlan/inclexcl8.8.05.pdf