# Is there a formula for this case of infinite inclusion-exclusion?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, inclusion-exclusion

Apparently, for any integers $m\ge 0,\ k\ge 1,$ and real $\alpha > 1$, the following series is convergent:
$$S_{k,m}(\alpha) =\sum\limits_{m<i_1<\ldots<i_k<\infty}\alpha^{-(i_1+\ldots+i_k)}.$$

**Examples** (computed with [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)):
$$\begin{align}
S_{1,m}(\alpha) &= \frac{\alpha^{-m}}{\alpha-1}\\
S_{2,m}(\alpha) &= \frac{\alpha^{-2m}}{(\alpha-1)^2 (\alpha+1)}\\
S_{3,m}(\alpha) &= \frac{\alpha^{-3m}}{(\alpha-1)^3(\alpha+1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)}\\
S_{4,m}(\alpha) &= \frac{\alpha^{-4m}}{(\alpha - 1)^4(\alpha + 1)^2(\alpha^2 + 1)(\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1)} 
\end{align}$$

**Question**: Is there a general pattern in these fractions that allows a single formula for $S_{k,m}(\alpha)$ in terms of some standard functions? Is there a closed form for the alternating series $S_{1,m}(\alpha)-S_{2,m}(\alpha)+S_{3,m}(\alpha)-\ldots$?

**Motivation**:
If $x_1 x_2 x_3 ...$ is an infinite string of random symbols i.i.d. uniform on a finite alphabet of size $\alpha\ge 2$, then, using [[infinite inclusion-exclusion]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/513175/16397), the probability that the string has a square prefix of length greater than $m$ is
$$P(\exists i>m:  x_1..x_i = x_{i+1}..x_{2i})=S_{1,m}(\alpha)-S_{2,m}(\alpha)+S_{3,m}(\alpha)-\ldots$$

(This is related to MSE postings [[here]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502527/where-if-ever-does-the-decimal-representation-of-pi-repeat-its-initial-segm), [[here]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502527/where-if-ever-does-the-decimal-representation-of-pi-repeat-its-initial-segm), and [[here]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459597/pi-as-an-infinite-set-of-integers).)

Comment: Your denominators simplify to $$\begin{align*}&\alpha-1\;,\\
&(\alpha^2-1)(\alpha-1)\;,\\&(\alpha^3-1)(\alpha^2-1)(\alpha-1)\;,\text{ and }\\&(\alpha^4-1)(\alpha^3-1)(\alpha^2-1)(\alpha-1)\;,\end{align*}$$ so it seems likely that $$S_{k,m}(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha^{-km}}{\prod_{i=1}^k(\alpha^i-1)}=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac1{\alpha^m(\alpha^i-1)}\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - Thanks, I missed that. I'm hoping the alternating series might be expressible in terms of some standard function, at least in the case of $m=0$.